# Dynamically change style of element with C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a chart with 4x LineSeries. I defined two different styles for representing the lines, and I want to be able to change the style applied to a particular LineSeries dynamically (based, for example, on the user tapping a button, etc).

I cannot seem to work out how to update the style from c#. Any help appreciated!

I have tried:

```
lineChartMood.PolylineStyle = this.Resources.PolylineStyle2 as Style;
```

but this returns a Null exception.

Here is the XAML for the page, including the style definitions:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="Bhutaan.ChartingTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bhutaan"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="PolylineStyle" TargetType="Polyline">
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="PolylineStyle2" TargetType="Polyline">
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="TEST" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="added" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,-0,12,0">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Great! That's been saved." FontSize="30" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <!-- Chart  -->
                    <charting:Chart
                        x:Name="myChart"
                        Margin="0,20,0,0"
                        Height="350"
                        Style="{StaticResource PhoneChartStyle}"
                        Template="{StaticResource PhoneChartPortraitTemplate}">

                        <!-- Series -->
                        <charting:LineSeries
                            x:Name="lineChartMood"
                            Title="Mood"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                            DependentValuePath="MoodValue"
                            IndependentValuePath="Timestamp"
                            PolylineStyle="{StaticResource PolylineStyle}" >

                            <charting:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="charting:LegendItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 5 0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </charting:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                        </charting:LineSeries>
                        <!-- Series -->
                        <charting:LineSeries
                            Title="Energy"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                            DependentValuePath="EnergyValue"
                            IndependentValuePath="Timestamp">
                            <charting:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="charting:LegendItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 5 0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </charting:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                        </charting:LineSeries>
                        <!-- Series -->
                        <charting:LineSeries
                            Title="Mental"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                            DependentValuePath="MentalValue"
                            IndependentValuePath="Timestamp">
                            <charting:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="charting:LegendItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 5 0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </charting:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                        </charting:LineSeries>
                        <!-- Series -->
                        <charting:LineSeries
                            Title="Hunger"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                            DependentValuePath="HungerValue"
                            IndependentValuePath="Timestamp">
                            <charting:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="charting:LegendItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 5 0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </charting:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                        </charting:LineSeries>
                    </charting:Chart>

                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>


</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: I suppose you are getting your nullpointerexception at the assignment line you have above right? which object is null? Could it be the lineChartMood or, the "PolylineStyle2" is incorrectly written? Can you tell more which object is null? Also, is the C# code above a code-behind the XAML?

Comment: Further debugging reveals that the style element is not null... it is the lineChartMood object that is null. Why could that be? In the code editor it does not come up with an error... but it seems to be null at runtime...

Comment: To be precise: based on feedback from the answers below, I updated that line to:

lineChartMood.PolylineStyle = App.Current.Resources["PolylineStyle2"] as Style;

Comment: Ok Good. So it seems that the problem is due to lineChartMood not being initialized. Therefore, i would conclude that the charting library you are using has a bug. It does use the XAML doc tree to identify what needs to be created but does not really put the instances back in the DOM (just a guess)

Comment: Let's see if we can access the polyline via the MyLineSeriesChart instance. I keep you posted

Comment: myChart.lineChartMood.PolylineStyle = App.Current.Resources["PolylineStyle2"] as Style;    

does not work... it seems I cannot reference the child element "lineChartMood" via the myChart parent element with dot notation..

Comment: Yes it is not there as the author of the library did not intend to add the children to the object model (by design or a bug, that you would have to ask them). You probably would have to redefine the definition of the style in the resources. Example, instead of TargetType=Polyline, you would have to set TargetType=Charting:Chart and work your way that path. Then in the code behind just to the style change as you initially intended but with myChart instead of lineChartMood. (That's one way.)

Comment: Ok, makes sense.. but how do I define the style of child elements through a style declaration for the parent myChart element?

Comment: This could be achieve through templatebinding. However, when i am inspecting the controltemplate of Chart in Blend, i am having some issues. Perhaps you could try to open the XAML in Expression Blend and edit a copy of myChart's template. Then you can try to rewire the values so that eventually, when you modify a dependency property on myChart, the changes would propagate and reflect in your view (e.g. Strokethickness={TemplateBinding <some-other-property-in-control-template-of-mychart>})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested your code and found the cause of the problem.

You get the NullReferenceException because the field `this.lineChartMood` isn't set by the application for some unknown reason.

You have to obtain this line series object by yourself. There are two possible ways to get it:

```
var lineSeriesWay1 = this.FindName("lineChartMood");
var lineSeriesWay2 = myChart.Series.OfType<LineSeries>().First(ls => ls.Name == "lineChartMood");
```

But I would recommend to set the field `this.lineSeriesMood` explicitly in the constructor, like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // because the code 'this.FindName("lineChartMood")' doesn't work in the constructor, I'll use the following line:
        this.lineChartMood = this.myChart.Series.OfType<LineSeries>().First(ls => ls.Name == "lineChartMood");

        // other code
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.lineChartMood.PolylineStyle = (Style)this.Resources["PolylineStyle2"];
        this.lineChartMood.Refresh(); // you should call this method so that the style is applied
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to reference to your series without exceptions.

Comment: thanks a lot for this - that worked! I can now run the code without exceptions. Perfect!
(I now have a subsequent problem... for some reason, I can only decrease the value of the polyLineThickness attribute... increasing it doesn't work. In other words, if it is set at 5 I can change it to 1 at run-time, but the opposite doesn't work).

thanks again for the answer- and sorry it took so long to accept it and reply (I have been travelling for work the past few weeks).
Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Why not add your resources in the App.xaml and refer them using App.Current.Resources?? I say this because I feel the program might not be able to refer the local resource defined on the specific page. I might be wrong. This is not a solution just a workaround.

Comment: I just tried this as well.. I still get the same Null reference exception... I must be doing something stupid wrong here!

Answer (score 2):

`lineChartMood.PolylineStyle = this.Resources.PolylineStyle2 as Style;`
should be
`lineChartMood.PolylineStyle = this.Resources["PolylineStyle2"] as Style;`??

Comment: define the styles in you app.xaml and access it via "application.current.resources["PolylineStyle2"]"
i think you are not in the same page when you try to get the resource?

Comment: definitely tried that... the style itself is not coming back as null, the lineChartMood object is. For some reason it is null at run-time... cannot figure out why, but Gros Lalo above thinks it might be a bug with the charting library I'm using...

Comment: @will it could be by design as well in case the authors never intented (or thought) one would use the lib like you are.